# Is the function F differentiable at any other points beside zero?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X:=L^2([0,1])$ and define $F:X\rightarrow X$ by $F(g)(t)=$ sin $g(t)$

From the definition of differentiability, it's also easily to cancel out several terms to prove that F is not differentiable at 0. However, I don't know how to prove whether F is differentiable at other points. Starting from the definition seems not available, any hints?

Comment: "F is continuously differentiable by some calculation." What does that mean?

Comment: @zhw I've edited it. I mean that I have proven this part by some calculation of inequalities.

Comment: Isn't a continuously differentiable function differentiable? Something doesn't make sense here.

Comment: yes, I confused it with another condition for X. I'll delete the statement

Comment: How did you show $DF(0)$ doesn't exist?